# Finding nearest point excluding last point LibGDX Java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to find a way to get a bunch of points to connect via the ShapeRenderer`s method of line(Vector2 first, Vector2 second). So I will explain then show image and code to help.

There is a List of type Vector2 and I need to find the next closest vertice and then exclude the first point. Here is an image of what I mean. I labeled the iterations of the loop in the image.

[image]

1st iteration.) it finds the closest point.

2nd iteration.) it sees that the first point is closer but still chooses the third point. This is the core problem, I need to make sure the second point finds the third point even though the first point is the closer one.

Here is the code I have tried to do this.

```
private void cleanVertices(Array<Vector2> verts){

    newVerts = new Array<Vector2>();
    Vector2 tmpKey, tmpClose = null;


    tmpKey = verts.get(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < verts.size; i++){

        for(int k = 0; k < (verts.size - 1); k++){
            if(k == i)
                continue;
            //Distance formula
            double dist = MathFactory.distance(verts.get(i), verts.get(k));
            if(MathFactory.distance(verts.get(i), verts.get(k + 1)) < dist){

                tmpClose = verts.get(k + 1);
            }else
                tmpClose = verts.get(i);


        }
        tmpKey = tmpClose;
        newVerts.add(tmpClose);
    }

}'
```

This does not accomplish what I need, instead, it seems to connect points closest on x-axis. I desperately need help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make a deep copy of the input parameter `verts` (i.e. a new `Array` containing the same list of references in `verts`).  Then iterate over that, but *remove* each point after you choose it as the next "nearest" neighbor.

I'm not familiar with the `Array` class, but an `ArrayList` would have the correct behavior when you remove an element.  At each point only unvisited points would remain in the list.

Answer (score 0):

since your problem is to find the closest vertex to the second vertex,which is the third in your case, without considering the first one. Make the second for loop starts from the position of the first for loop in every iteration ( k = i). Meaning that the second for loop will not consider the first vertex as point to calculate the distance from.